# How to migrate GPG trust database from one machine to another?

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to copy my gpg related files over from an old machine to a new one.

I've worked out how to copy the keys over: [How to import secret gpg key (copied from one machine to another)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/how-to-import-secret-gpg-key-copied-from-one-machine-to-another) but this leaves me with gpg complaining that it doesn't trust the imported keys.

How do I transfer the trust db from one machine to another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy `~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg` from one machine to another.

You can also export the ownertrust values (which are the ones that matter) and import them on the new machine:

```
gpg --export-ownertrust > otrust.txt

rm ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
gpg --import-ownertrust < otrust.txt
```

See the [`gpg` manpage](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html) for details (although the version on the website doesn't say much more than I have).