# List and export GPG keys

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to migrate a (PHP) software module into a new server (from a CentOS 6.9 to an Ubuntu 16.04). In a certain part of a process, the code tries to launch the following command:

```
gpg --no-tty --sign --encrypt --armor --passphrase=whatever --local-user A188E1E4! --recipient A188E1E4
```

So I'm trying to export the private/public key pair from the working server.

I'm stuck at this point, I've tried to manage it with [this very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/how-to-import-secret-gpg-key-copied-from-one-machine-to-another) but I don't know the name and path where the key should be.

I've tried to run `gpg --list-keys` but:

> gpg: directory '/home/my-username/.gnupg' created
>
> gpg: new configuration file /home/my-username/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
>
> gpg: WARNING: options in '/home/my-username/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
>
> gpg: keyring '/home/my-usernameo/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
>
> gpg: /home/my-username/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created

I don't know which user is the code using to launch the command.
Maybe I would need a way to list all the keys, not only the current user, so I can see which key I need to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpg` will try to load the keys from `~/.gnupg` and will not list "All keys in the system" as each user has a separate keyring. You cannot do this.

In your case the `gpg` application will try to list the keys from `www-data`, `php` or what is the name of the user that owns the `php` process.

You can change the location of the keys by manipulating the `GNUPGHOME` or `HOME` environment variable, or by setting the  `--homedir` to  `gpg`. This option is not available in all `gpg` versions.